# Recovering lost work on a GIT project

Tags: git

First time I took part in a project that uses GIT.
And maybe GIT throw out my work of last week. I worked with a few versioning managers (SVN, Clearcase ...) and I never lost anything, so I hope I can save my work even this time.

I had to do some programming on an existing project. I cloned and worked on it. I modified a few files, and I renamed some files. I did a few commits. When I wanted to push on BRANCH_B, I noticed that it's not possible, since I was on BRANCH_A. So I went on BRANCH_B:

```
user@user MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/my-prj (BRANCH_A)
$ git checkout BRANCH_B
fatal: cannot create directory at 'prj/path/to/': Permission denied

user@user MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/my-prj (BRANCH_A)
$ git checkout BRANCH_B
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        modified:   prj/path/to/modified_file1.java
        ...
        modified:   prj/path/to/modified_fileN.java

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

OK, so something did not work and was aborted. Nothing happened and I am still on BRANCH_A.
It didn't even ask for confirmation, so I don't need to worry about anything.
Let's try the status:

```
user@user MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/my-prj (BRANCH_A)
$ git status
On branch BRANCH_A
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/BRANCH_A' by 18 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   prj/path/to/modified_file1.java
        ...
        modified:   prj/path/to/modified_fileN.java
        deleted:    prj/path/to/renamed_file1.java
        ...
        deleted:    prj/path/to/renamed_fileN.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But on my computer all the changes of last week are lost! So I try to "undo" the previous command:

```
user@user MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/my-prj (BRANCH_A)
$ git checkout BRANCH_A
M       prj/path/to/modified_file1.java
M       ...
M       prj/path/to/modified_fileN.java
D       prj/path/to/renamed_file1.java
D       ...
D       prj/path/to/renamed_fileN.java
Already on 'BRANCH_A'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/BRANCH_A' by 18 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

user@user MINGW64 /c/git_workspace/my-prj (BRANCH_A)
$ cd prj/path/to/
bash: cd: prj/path/to/: No such file or directory
```

But my changes didn't come back.

> - Question: what happened and how can I have back my changes?

---

Notes:

1. I gave twice the first command but I don't remember why, and I don't know why the first time it didn't work but the second time it "worked". I noticed that only after starting writing here. **Update: now i remember that first time the directory was open by freecommander, that's why there was no permission for writing.** (sorry for that)
2. As you noticed, I never really moved from BRANCH_A.
3. one hope. I have gitk: in it I see that BRANCH_A is a yellow point, and after that i can see a red point with the name: «Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index». There i can see the differences with my files. I don't know why it says they aren't committed, since i committed few times. I could copy-paste the differences...

Comment: Stop changing branches when you have uncommitted changes. That is why you are running into problems. Either reset them or stash them... or commit them obviously

Comment: I don't know what your "changes from last week" are so I can't help you

Comment: why "Permission denied"? Do you run out of space? or you have wrong fs permissions? Seems like a filesystem error to me...

Comment: @JoePhilllips Doesn't sound like he had uncommitted changes when he first ran git checkout.

Comment: Good point. It just looks like he doesn't have permission to some files so the checkout aborted and left dirty files around... just fix the permission problems, obviously. I still don't see how he would've lost anything in this case though

Comment: @JoePhilllips I think he's just concerned because the failed checkout left older files from BRANCH_B in his working directory, and those files don't have the changes he just made on BRANCH_A.

Comment: Maybe you can find some of your old commits in the reflog. Try `git reflog` and `git reflog --all`. When you've found where BRANCH_A should be, `git branch -f BRANCH_A sha1` to fix it. If you're lucky, `BRANCH_A{1}` will be good. But the "Permission denied" is the root problem and definitely deserves to get some attention. If you don't know why it happened, you don't know it won't happen again, and you can see what a mess it leaves.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all your changes "from last week" were already committed to the repository on `BRANCH_A`, you can get those back in your working directory by running `git reset --hard`. **Don't run that if you didn't commit your changes from last week, as it could cause them to be deleted.** If you're not sure, you can save all your current uncommitted changes to a temporary stash by running `git stash save` instead. That's safer, but not necessary if you're sure you already committed your previous changes.

As for why the checkout failed in the first place, it sounds like it partially failed the first time due to some kind of permissions error. I don't fully understand the permissions model on Windows, but I'd recommend checking the properties of the folder you're working in to ensure you have full read/write permissions on that folder and all subfolders. Or alternately, maybe try moving the repository to your Documents folder, or somewhere else your current user has permission to modify without admin privileges.

The second time the checkout failed was due to changed files created by the first failed checkout, so that failure shouldn't be an issue once you fix the first error and reset your working directory back to `BRANCH_A`.

Comment: FYI, I keep my repos in C:\repos\ on windows and never have problems

Comment: @JoePhilllips Yeah, I'm actually unsure of what's caused the permissions problem in the first place. I'll add a few more suggestions of things to try.

Comment: Probably locked files that are open or something

Comment: @JoePhilllips That's what I'd assume if the error was on modifying or deleting a file, but this error was on *creating* a directory.

Comment: Thanks, now i remember, i had freecommander open on that directory, that's why 1st time the command didn't work. I'll update the notes on the question. Yesterday i was a little bit in panic so i couldn't think properly.

Comment: I saved the files that were renamed, thanks God they were open in Notepad++; Np++ thought that they were deleted and asked me what to do: so i choosen "save copy as..." option. The other suggestions from you i will try, but i will do that when somebody more expert than me will be present (everybody on xmas holiday now). Thanks guys for your help and have nice new year.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your suggestions; I asked a colleague and finally I solved as following:

```
#First of all, thanks to gitk i saw all changes i did with my work; I copy-pasted them in a txt file as backup. Then i went to the console:

#I am on BRANCH_A

$ git reset --hard    # I wouldn't do this without a backup copy of my changes in a safe place

$ git checkout BRANCH_B

#I am on BRANCH_B, I try a merge
$ git merge BRANCH_A

$ git push origin BRANCH_B
#Now all my changes are on branch_B, where they should
```

In my **local** BRANCH_A i also see some changes that should be only on BRANCH_B, but it's not important, since I won't push such changes on "real" BRANCH_A and the rest of the world will see them only on BRANCH_B (according what I understood).